# html minification no longer a factor?

Tags: google-pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm not seeing **html minification recommendation** in neither the pagespeed insights nor lighthouse.

**Can someone confirm this is indeed the case and we dont need to minify html anymore to satisfy google?**

**P.S.**
For starters - i would be so so very happy about it if that's the case.
Because benefits are imho so very minimal when considering we also use gzip and brotli, and opportunity for management to force through some get-rich-quick **html minification** scheme is removed. which is exactly what happened.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the description of the [tag:seo] tag.

Comment: No official guidance on it but other than removing white space the benefits are minimal. The recommendation was removed from Lighthouse a long time ago I am sure (when v4 was deprecated, at least that is what I seem to remember). Google has **never** cared if you minify HTML for clarity - the performance is all they care about.

Answer (score 0):

The importance is the speed - if you have a minified code (HTML, CSS, JS) it always comes a little faster. The formating costs time. In my opinion it is precised a little more sharply, to get a better feeling, what is wenting wrong.

HTH